# solvePnP object_points / image_points shape?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to call solvePnP with the following arguments.

```
apriltag_object_points = np.array([(-1, -1, 0), (-1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, -1, 0)], dtype=np.float)

camera_matrix_left = np.eye(3)

dist_left = np.zeros((5, 1))

image_points = np.array(detection.position, dtype=np.float)

cv2.solvePnPRansac(apriltag_object_points, image_points, camera_matrix_left, dist_left)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (CV_IS_MAT(_src) && CV_IS_MAT(_dst) && (_src->rows == 1 || _src->cols == 1) && (_dst->rows == 1 || _dst->cols == 1) && _src->cols + _src->rows - 1 == _dst->rows + _dst->cols - 1 && (CV_MAT_TYPE(_src->type) == CV_32FC2 || CV_MAT_TYPE(_src->type) == CV_64FC2) && (CV_MAT_TYPE(_dst->type) == CV_32FC2 || CV_MAT_TYPE(_dst->type) == CV_64FC2)) in cvUndistortPoints, file /Users/travis/miniconda3/conda-bld/opencv_1506476120161/work/opencv-3.3.0/modules/imgproc/src/undistort.cpp, line 312
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Code/project/file.py", line 139, in <module>
    ret = cv2.solvePnPRansac(apriltag_object_points, image_points, camera_matrix_left, dist_left)
cv2.error: /Users/travis/miniconda3/conda-bld/opencv_1506476120161/work/opencv-3.3.0/modules/imgproc/src/undistort.cpp:312: error: (-215) CV_IS_MAT(_src) && CV_IS_MAT(_dst) && (_src->rows == 1 || _src->cols == 1) && (_dst->rows == 1 || _dst->cols == 1) && _src->cols + _src->rows - 1 == _dst->rows + _dst->cols - 1 && (CV_MAT_TYPE(_src->type) == CV_32FC2 || CV_MAT_TYPE(_src->type) == CV_64FC2) && (CV_MAT_TYPE(_dst->type) == CV_32FC2 || CV_MAT_TYPE(_dst->type) == CV_64FC2) in function cvUndistortPoints
```

It looks like there's a problem with the shape of my arguments, but they seem to be fine...

```
apriltag_object_points.shape == (4, 3)
image_points.shape == (4, 2)
```

Do the image points have to be homogenous? Do I just have to `hstack` a column vector of `1`'s to `image_points`?

Comment: "Do the image points have to be homogenous?" The docs say `Nx2` or `2xN` or two-channel (i.e. `Nx1x2`), so it doesn't seem like that would solve your problem. Can you create your `image_points` with hardcoded values so that anyone could run this program to reproduce your error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is simply *wrong* for this function as it's implemented in Python. The docs for [`solvePnP()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp) and [`solvePnPRansac()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnpransac) both state:

> **Parameters:**
>
> **objectPoints** – Array of object points in the object coordinate space, 3xN/Nx3 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 3-channel, where N is the number of points. `vector<Point3f>` can be also passed here.
>
> **imagePoints** – Array of corresponding image points, 2xN/Nx2 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 2-channel, where N is the number of points. `vector<Point2f>` can be also passed here.

So you assumed you were good using a (N, 3) and (N, 2) array for your inputs. However, the error code says otherwise. Let's break it down:

> CV_IS_MAT(_src) && CV_IS_MAT(_dst) && (_src->rows == 1 || _src->cols == 1) && (_dst->rows == 1 || _dst->cols == 1) && _src->cols + _src->rows - 1 == _dst->rows + _dst->cols - 1 && (CV_MAT_TYPE(_src->type) == CV_32FC2 || CV_MAT_TYPE(_src->type) == CV_64FC2) && (CV_MAT_TYPE(_dst->type) == CV_32FC2 || CV_MAT_TYPE(_dst->type) == CV_64FC2)

Ok, they're numpy arrays, so we can probably discard the first two. But then in the next checks we see something interesting:

> (_src->rows == 1 || _src->cols == 1) && (_dst->rows == 1 || _dst->cols == 1)

It's checking that there are only one row or one column in `src` and `dst`. In other words, it's expecting your points strictly in the second version that it states in the docs; it wants a multi-channel point array. This means that the first coordinate is on one channel of a matrix, second coordinate in the next channel, etc.

So if we simply reshape your points into a multi-channel array:

```
>>> apriltag_object_points = apriltag_object_points.reshape(4,1,3)
>>> image_points = image_points.reshape(4,1,2)
>>> it_works, rvec, tvec, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(apriltag_object_points, image_points, camera_matrix_left, dist_left)
>>> it_works
True
```

It works!

Future pro-tip: in every function that OpenCV *does* allow points in a `(npoints, ncoords)` format, it also accepts them in a `(npoints, 1, ncoords)` format AFAIK. However, some functions *only* work with the latter format. Therefore, if you're using point coordinates in OpenCV with Python, it's probably best to assume your points should be in a multi-channel array, where the number of channels is the number of coordinate axes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent a good day and a half trusting the docs and wondering where I was going wrong. I'm sure this will be a great resource for future readers

Comment: @Carpetfizz I've answered a number of similar questions on Stack for point transformation functions. Even the first time I used the functions I had to look at the documentation of *multiple* functions to iron out that fact. The documentation could be more helpful here for Python, but it's difficult to know the best way to implement that since OpenCV is ultimately a C++ library. Oddly enough these checks seems that it would break the C++ version as well using the same type of input you did, and the docs specifically state otherwise. I'll check on OpenCV's GitHub and open an issue if necessary.

Comment: @Carpetfizz I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9764) as I didn't see any pull requests which would have fixed this nor open issues that discuss it.